# Como eu faço para poder apresentar em uma lista na na mesma linha da tabela de um groupBy?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma listagem e estou com uma dificuldade para apresentar na mesma linha da tabela dados `groupBy` eu não estou conseguindo listar numa mesma linha esses dados, no caso `DT_PONTO` retorna dois valores `S` para entrada e `N` para saída (e cada valor tem seu próprio ID) e na tabela html eu queria esses valores para duas coluna distintas.

```
   public function scopes()
        {


        $workes=Workers::find(20) ;

        $date1 = '2015-10-05';
        $date2 = '2015-10-05';  

        $cargos   =   $workes->cargos()->get('NM_CARGO');
        $pontos   =   $workes->punchcards()->where([
                                                   ['DT_PONTO', '>=', $date1],
                                                   ['DT_PONTO', '<=', $date2]
                                                                            ])
     ->with('markings')->get();   

     foreach($pontos as $valorP){

          $marks = $valorP->markings()->get();
          $resultP[]= $valorP;
        foreach($marks as $mark){
            $resu1=[
                   'CD_PONTO'=>($mark->CD_PONTO),
                   'DT_PONTO'=>($valorP->DT_PONTO),
                   'HR_MARCACAO'=>($mark->HR_MARCACAO)
                 ];





           $tes1[] = $resu1;

        }}

        $retorns1= new Collection($tes1);



        $fills = $retorns1->groupBy('VF_ENTRADA');


        $fills->toArray();

          return view("modules.education.reports.common.table_score_structure", compact( 'retorns','fills'));
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue uma demonstração, está muito vago o que você passou mas entendi o seguinte.

Uma das formas corretas

```
$pontos   =   $workes->punchcards()->whereRaw("DT_PONTO <= {$date1}")->whereRaw"DT_PONTO <= {$date2}")->groupBy('column')->get(); // ou troca o get por first para pegar o primeiro
```

Outra forma se for o que eu entendi

```
Workers::with('punchcard')->where('id', 20)->whereHas('punchcard', function($query){
  $query->whereRaw('DT_PONTO', '>=', $date1);
  $query->whereRaw('DT_PONTO', '<=', $date2);
})->groupBy('column')->get() // ou pode usar first fiz um código sem testar caso não funcione faça outro WhereHas e passa o dt_ponto no whereRaw com menor igual.
```

Comment: Quando eu uso o ' whereRaw ' da erro de Syntax, mas no caso o relacionamento e entre três tabela  Workers, Punchcards, Markings e o  groupBy seria para a tabela Markings no qual tem uma coluna que faz registro de entrada e saída de funcionário e meu problema principal e que na hora de repassar os dados para a VIEW eu não to conseguindo em uma mesma linha da tabela html (blade) coloca um valor que registra   a entrada do funcionário  e saída .

Comment: Passa dois WhereHas então

Comment: O Group By vai pegar todos dados repetidos e vai ajuntar

Comment: Editei os primeiros whereRaw para ficar certo